# Is there Rx.NET for .NET Core?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, .net-core

Found https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/148, but I could not figure out the bottom line - where is Rx.NET for .NET Core and how to get it?

I am using Enterprise Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with .NET Core installed.

Comment: Did you look on Nuget at all? https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive.Core/

Comment: I did. R# suggested searching NuGet for a package containing the class `Observable`. I did and it found Rx-Linq 2.2.5, which is incompatible with .NET Core.  I will check the System.Reactive now.

Comment: The situation around the Reactive Community is difficult enough (they have two Github orgs, a recently re-organized .NET community and recently renamed all their projects) ... I think it is fair that there is some confusion. Thanks @mark

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, but Rx.NET namespaces and packages have been renamed to System.Reactive as [described here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET#breaking-changes).

> The NuGet packages have changed their package naming in the move from v2.x.x to v3.0.0
>
> - Rx-Main is now System.Reactive
> - Rx-Core is now System.Reactive.Core
> - Rx-Interfaces is now System.Reactive.Interfaces
> - Rx-Linq is now System.Reactive.Linq
> - Rx-PlatformServices is now System.Reactive.PlatformServices
> - Rx-Testing is now Microsoft.Reactive.Testing

You can add the NuGet package by editing your `project.json` and adding a reference to `System.Reactive`

```
  (...)
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "System.Reactive": "3.0.0"    <------------- 
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are right, of course. Somehow I was convinced that searching NuGet for a package with `Observable` class would give me the right package right away. Instead of relying on R# I should have searched the Rx.Net github page. Thanks.

Comment: I agree NuGet search needs to be redone. You can also try the reverse package search. It allows to search by class name/namespace  http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/